# ProGuard Obfuscate Error, plobleme with my Dao?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, proguard

I try to obfuscated my apk, but i have a problem with Dao.[Image Problem Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdy4u.jpg) [Second Image Problem Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3zk5.jpg), here below its my code, for de proguard-rules, why class i need to keep?

```
-useuniqueclassmembernames
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontoptimize
-dontshrink

-keepparameternames

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keep class my.dao.package.*$Properties {
public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class my.dao.package.** {
public java.lang.String TABLENAME;
}
```

Comment: added your full error  it is not clear in picture

Answer (score 0):

I solve my question like this...

// The 'xxx' its my packageName where i put my dao's

```
-keep class xxx.dao.**{*;}
```

Apparently there are ploblems with my Dao class, i not Obfuscate this class.